# Julia language: quotes in run() are not recognized? Pipeline error

Tags: julia

Julia is ignoring quotes when I use run(), e.g.:

```
run(`cat file.txt | sed "s/blah/hi/"`)
```

ignores the quotes, which are required.

```
\"
```

does not work...

*EDIT*: The error is with the pipeline:

```
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: sed: No such file or directory
cat: s/blah/hi/: No such file or directory
ERROR: failed process: Process(`cat file.txt | sed s/blah/hi/`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]
 in pipeline_error at process.jl:502
 in run at ./process.jl:479
```

Comment: What version of Julia are you using?

Comment: I am using Julia Version 0.3.7

Comment: What happens exactly when you run the first code block?

Comment: @AlexA. Ahh, it must be an error with the pipeline? My error is:

    cat: |: No such file or directory
    cat: sed: No such file or directory
    cat: s/blah/hi/: No such file or directory
    ERROR: failed process: Process(`cat file.txt | sed s/blah/hi/`,     ProcessExited(1)) [1]
     in pipeline_error at process.jl:502
 in run at ./process.jl:479

Comment: You should add the error to the post, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|` does not create a pipe inside of Julia backtick syntax. Instead, you are invoking the `cat` program with four arguments:

- `file.txt`
- `|`
- `sed`
- `s/blah/hi/`

Since these files are unlikely to all exist, `cat` terminates with an error. Note that `sed` does not require quotes around the last argument. In fact, if it did get quotes then it wouldn't do what you want at all since the program would be a single string literal. It's the shell that sees the double quotes and passes their contents to `sed` as a single argument. In this case, since there are no spaces or other characters that are special to most shells between the quotes, it makes no difference. To accomplish what you want you can do this:

```
run(`cat file.txt` |> `sed "s/blah/hi/"`)
```

The double quotes are optional as they are in the shell since there are no spaces or other special characters inside of the argument to `sed`.

Comment: @AlexA.  Julia's [Pipeline](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/#pipelines) documentation.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Ugh, I'm dense. Should have just looked. Thanks for the link, I appreciate it.